# How many independent messages can have a single hour of the transcript?

Tags: support, chat

If we look at one of the most active sites of SE, The Bridge, transcript one may notice that they have several boxes for near each active hour of the day. Now, I know there are rooms with a single sheet, but is there a maximum of messages that can be spawned over an hour that doesn't break into another sheet? Or each hour breakdown is done with a minimum amount of messages?

[image]

Comment: 22:00 to 0:00 is two hours. Why not see how many were in each of those 1-hour spans and take a guess? Or analyze several days worth to get a better idea of the cutoff? This doesn't seem that complicated to figure out with a bit of elbowgrease and some jQuery...